# HTML index not applying CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm relatively new to Web Design, and I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27JtRAI3QO8) to create a responsive webpage. Thing is, there seems to be a problem with my .CSS, because the webpage is not looking as it should. Also, I am just opening the index.html in Edge, from my webpage folder, don't know if that has something to do. Inside this folder, I have the index.html and the assets folder. Inside assets, I have several folders containing the css, js, img, pdf resources. This is what the html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--==================== UNICONS ====================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">        
    <!--==================== SWIPER CSS ====================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/swiper-bundle.min.css" >    
    <!--==================== CSS ====================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/styles.css" >

    <title>Luis Garcia WebPage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--==================== HEADER ====================-->
    <header class="header" id="header">
        <nav class="nav container">
            <a href="#" class="nav__logo">Luis</a>

            <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
                <ul class="nav__list grid">
                    <li class="nav__item">
                        <a href="#home" class="nav__link active-link">
                            <i class="uil uil-estate"></i> Home
                            **************etc*********
```

And my the start of my .css (it is too long to post it whole, i can attach if later if needed):

```
/*==================== GOOGLE FONTS ====================*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');

/*==================== VARIABLES CSS ====================*/
:root {
    --header-height: 3rem;

    /*========== Colors ==========*/
    /* Change favorite color */
    --hue-color: 185; /*Purple 250 - Green 142 - Blue 230 - Pink 340*/

    /* HSL color mode */
    --first-color: hsl((var(--hue-color)), 76%, 61%);
    --first-color-second: hsl((var(--hue-color)), 76%, 61%);
    --first-color-alt: hsl((var(--hue-color)), 57%, 53%);
    --first-color-lighter: hsl((var(--hue-color)), 92%, 85%);
    --title-color: hsl((var(--hue-color)), 8%, 15%);
    --text-color: hsl((var(--hue-color)), 8%, 45%);
    --text-color-light: hsl((var(--hue-color)), 8%, 65%);
    --input-color: hsl((var(--hue-color)), 70%, 96%);
    --body-color: hsl((var(--hue-color)), 60%, 99%);
    --container-color: #FFF;
    --scroll-bar-color: hsl((var(--hue-color)), 12%, 90%);
    --scroll-thumb-color: hsl((var(--hue-color)), 12%, 80%);

    /*========== Font and typography ==========*/
    --body-font:'Poppins', sans-serif;

    /* .5rem = 8px, 1rem = 16px, 1.5rem = 24px ... */
    --big-font-size: 2rem;
    --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
    --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
    --h3-font-size: 1.125rem;
    --normal-font-size: .938rem;
    --small-font-size: .813rem;
    --smaller-font-size: .75rem;
```

This is the webpage form the tutorial:

[image]

And this is my webpage:

[image]

Somehow, the CSS is not applied.

I am getting this errors if I inspect the webpage:

[image]
[image]

And the line where the css gets loaded:

[image]

Sorry for the big post, but hope you can help this newbie :)

EDIT 1: The main.js file is attached at the end of the html, as well as some fancy swiper functionality for the webpage:

```
<!--==================== SWIPER JS ====================-->
    <script src="assets/js/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!--==================== MAIN JS ====================-->
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have the link for the tutorial?

Comment: Yep! It's this one (it is also in the question description): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27JtRAI3QO8

Comment: It's not a complex website but your experience quite far from what you are trying to do. I suggest you to find something simpler like examples in `w3schools.com`.

Comment: @erman999 Thanks for the advice! Even tho I'm new to frontend, I have more than 4y experience in programming, mostly backend and ML/DL... I think I understand 60-70% of the proccess of the tutorial, seems pretty straight and logic... Anyway, as said, thanks for the advice, If no one finds the error here, I will try to go step by step :D

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 possible errors. First, you haven't created or attached a Java Script File and that is why you are seeing some differences with the tutorial. Second, the font that you are using cannot be found and therefore you get some errors.

Comment: Hi Elina, thanks for your answer! I did created a JS with the funcionality. The funcionality of the webpage works just fine, buttons take me to their sections (About me, contact, portfolio, etc). The file is inside asset/js/main.js. Don't know why she writes the main.js attached at the end of html, but I'm gonna edit the question so there is no doubt!